# print inside puts in Ruby

Tags: ruby

When I use print inside puts the iterator gets printed at the and of each print. Why is that happening?

```
def hop_hop_hop(number_of_exercises)
  for i in (1..number_of_exercises)
    puts "#{i.times { print 'hop!' } } One more time..."
  end
end

hop_hop_hop(3)
```

I want this:

```
hop! One more time...
hop! hop! One more time...
hop! hop! hop! One more time...
```

Code gives me:

```
hop!1 One more time...
hop! hop!2 One more time...
hop! hop! hop!3 One more time...
```

Comment: Well, if you just want to fix _your_ solution, make `i.times {}` to return `nil` as `nil` is effectively discarded when string is interpolated: `puts "#{i.times { print 'hop!' }.tap { break nil } } One more time..."`.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin when cure is worse than the disease :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev please do not shoot the pianist. He is doing his best in answering the question stated :shrug:

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin: no shooting, just a friendly taunt :)

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin: btw, can be done simpler: `i.times {} && nil`. Or even `i.times {}; nil`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to `print` inside a `puts`.

Try:

```
puts "#{'hop! ' * i}One more time..."
```

And why is the number coming into the output in your example? It's because `i.times` returns the `i`, which is `3` in your example. So, in essence, your example was doing this:

```
def hop_three_times
   print 'hop!'
   print 'hop!'
   print 'hop!'
   return 3
end

i = hop_three_times
puts "#{i} One more time..."
```

Comment: Neither does the original example. I could create an array and use `join`, but I believe this level of question would not benefit from such complication.

Comment: `puts "#{'hop! ' * i}One more time..."` – doesn't have to be complicated.